# i want to know about the code of .exe file which is in command prompt

Tags: reverse-engineering, extract, cmd

I have a problem of to open(EXTRACT) a command prompt.
I want to see the code inside this "a*.exe" file.
can u suggest me as if i am not aware of this field(software).
how to extract cmd.exe file.

Comment: @Vitor: I was able to slice through a specific part of `cmd.exe` with IDA Pro with only minimal knowledge of x86 assembly, though. Ok, still took quite some time but was an interesting experience ;)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you don't know software, you won't understand anything you see in an .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you cannot see the code of an executable file (short answer).

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to reverse engineer .exe's in windows.
Make sure you have 7za.exe in your system32 folder.
In this example i will pull the source of cmd.exe.

```
copy C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe C:\cmd.7z
7z e c:\cmd.7z
```

Then you go to the extracted folder from cmd.7z and there you have the source files.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

But if you are pretty sure that you indeed *have* the knowledge and experience you need, you might want take a look at this PE/COFF format specification over here:

```
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121460
```

The specification is very clear and concise; it might be just what you want. With some work, you can inspect a PE/COFF file with your program iff you have the right k&e.*

HTH

-- pete

* Heh! Lily Tomlin's Ernestine: " ... 'k' as in 'knowledge' ... "